# Timing multiple client events from Blazor server as precisely as possible

Tags: timer, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the idea of using a singleton service event to coordinate timing among multiple users.  Specifically, I will present a quiz-game question to players simultaneously.

What method would I use to broadcast a Timer event (3, 2, 1, go. . . ) to multiple users at the same time?

--edit--
I'm thinking about showing images, which might take some time to load.  Does Blazor trigger "OnAfterRender" when the markup is set, or when assets are actually loaded by the client?

Comment: You just need some Push mechanism.  The expected differences would be in the millisecond range, hardly a problem that needs solving. And try to avoid Singletons.

Comment: Okay that's a nice start.  I'd say any difference under about 0.1-0.25 sec would be an acceptable tolerance.  Let me refine / improve my question a little and see what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a singleton for this. It is possible to do so, but no recommended. You can use the [eventing mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events) to accomplish this. Have an event in the singleton that callers can subscribe to and then when a certain event happens, the handlers get invoked.

However, this sounds like an excellent use case for using SignalR. I do the same thing to push information from one device to another without having to do the heavy lifting myself. You can use the groups feature and add one or more users to a group. Then you just fire off a message to the group and all users get it. SignalR is very easy to set up and you can run it right inside your Asp.Net Core application. There is no need for anything external.

Comment: Okay, between answers from Henk, enet (in another thread) and you, it's looking like SignalR is going to be the ticket.  I WAS going to use a singleton as you described, but I'm pretty sold on not doing that now.

Comment: Yeah, and not to mention you have to deal with thread safety and other things if you want to use a singleton.

Comment: Okay I've started looking up SignalR, and I'm confused.  The samples I've found are all WASM projects, but I'm using Blazor server, not Web Assembly.  What is SignalR actually doing for me?

Comment: Here is a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-build-blazor-server-chat-app) from Microsoft on how to build a simple Blazor Server chat app. Signalr basically handles the communication for you.

Comment: In that example you do `await _hubConnection.SendAsync("Broadcast", _username, message);`. That will send a message to all listeners, because of `await Clients.All.SendAsync("Broadcast", username, message);` in `BlazorChatSampleHub`. Other Blazor sessions will receive the message because they all subscribe to it by way of `_hubConnection.On<string, string>("Broadcast", BroadcastMessage);`. This does mean that the user who sends the message also gets it, but you can just do `Client.Others` instead of `Client.All` when you send in the hub, so that it only gets broadcast to "other" clients.